# Symbols outputting as a question mark '?'

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to make a twitter shoutout tool. The tool will search the Twitter API to see who has retweeted a status/tweet, and then it will tweet each user.

It will do this by looping through each screen name within this JSON feed:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/{status_id}/retweeted_by.json

I want the text of the tweet to look like this:

[image]

This is the text I want to be in the tweet:

★┏━━┓▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂ ★┃┏━┛╲▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂┈▕ ★┃┗┳━┳┓┏┓┏━┳┓┏┓┏┓▕▏▕ ★┃┏┫┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃┃▕▏▕ ★┃┃┃┃┃┗┫┗┫┃┃┗┛┗┛┃┈╲╱ ★┗┛┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━━━━

However, this is how it shows on twitter (a bunch of question marks.):
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is here? What's causing this? and how could I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The font you're using doesn't support the old-school box drawing characters, most likely. You'll also have to output those characters with `<br>` line breaks or in a `<pre>` block, because HTML doesn't honor standard linebreaks in text.

Comment: You could use `nl2br()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php, to convert newlines to BR.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the very beginning of your file (make sure you don't have spaces or lines before this, or you'll get a `headers already sent` error):

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Your PHP code
?>
```

When you do the `echo`, place it inside `<pre>` tags to preserve line breaks:

```
echo '<pre>' . $yourTweet . '</pre>';
```